# Invalid TOKEN C#

Tags: c#, sql

Me da estos errores al querer compilar mi proyecto en c#, no tengo idea por que, alguien me puede guiar por favor.

```
        private void KitchenSetup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*
              //Para guardar los datos del DGV1 en la nueva base de datos
 string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["keyconfig"].ConnectionString; 

using (MySqlSqlConnection conn = new MySqlSqlConnection(connstring)) { 
    conn.Open(); 
            */
    string query = "INSERT INTO kitchen (id, nombre) VALUES (?id, ?nombre)"; 
    MySqlSqlCommand cmd = new MySqlSqlCommand(query, conn); 


    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) { 
        cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["id"].Value)); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nombre", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["nombre"].Value)); 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
}


            if (this.Owner.Owner != null)
            {
                this.Owner.Enabled = false;
                this.Owner.Visible = false;
                this.Location = new Point(
                    ((this.Owner.Owner.Width - this.Width) / 2),
                    ((this.Owner.Owner.Height - this.Height) / 2)
                );
            }
            else
            {
                this.Owner.Enabled = false;
                this.Location = new Point(
                     ((this.Owner.Width - this.Width) / 2),
                     ((this.Owner.Height - this.Height) / 2)
                 );
            }
            this.TxtIpBd.Text = this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ConnectionIp;
            this.GetScreenId();
            this.GetKitchenArea();
            this.GetTableSection();
            this.GetLicenceType();
            this.SelectDataGridView();
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si voy comentando el codigo o moviendole, los errores solo cambian de sitio pero son muy similares, estoy atento si requieres mas codigo, saludos

Comment: Creo que tienes que revisar que tengas bien tus "{" y tus "}".

Comment: puedes poner tu clase completa, incluyendo el namespace?

Answer (score 1):

El error ocurre porque cierras tu función y agregas código luego de cerrada cosa que no se puede agregar directamente en la clase.

Lo que paso es que comentaste el using pero no comentaste la llave que lo cierra por eso salta el error.

Bastaría con comentar una de las llaves despues de tu `foreach`...

```
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
//}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que deberias ser un poco mas prolijo para programar, identar el codigo de forma correcta es el primer paso.

Cuando comentaste la linea

```
using (MySqlSqlConnection conn = new MySqlSqlConnection(connstring)) {
```

al usar el bloque `/*` y `*/`, dejaste una llave `}` suelta, lo que hace que el `if` quede invalido.

Si eliminas el codigo comentado seguro se reducen los errores

```
private void KitchenSetup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string query = "INSERT INTO kitchen (id, nombre) VALUES (?id, ?nombre)"; 
    MySqlSqlCommand cmd = new MySqlSqlCommand(query, conn); 

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) { 
        cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["id"].Value)); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nombre", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["nombre"].Value)); 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 



    if (this.Owner.Owner != null)
    {
        this.Owner.Enabled = false;
        this.Owner.Visible = false;
        this.Location = new Point(
            ((this.Owner.Owner.Width - this.Width) / 2),
            ((this.Owner.Owner.Height - this.Height) / 2)
        );
    }
    else
    {
        this.Owner.Enabled = false;
        this.Location = new Point(
             ((this.Owner.Width - this.Width) / 2),
             ((this.Owner.Height - this.Height) / 2)
         );
    }
    this.TxtIpBd.Text = this.bizKitchenConfiguration.ConnectionIp;
    this.GetScreenId();
    this.GetKitchenArea();
    this.GetTableSection();
    this.GetLicenceType();
    this.SelectDataGridView();
}
```

pero no se solucionan todos los errores porque la variable `conn` que usas en el `MySqlCommand` no estara definida